# Nested if statements confusion - 'Forgot my password'

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is there anyway to quickly identify the problem with nested if statements, getting constant errors saying one too many } then getting 'This count is unaware if curly braces are inside of a string' when deleting certain brackets:

*Was wondering if someone could walk me through how to debug this properly*

*my code is to reset a users password*

**Here's my code:**

```
<?php 
if (!$username && !$id){
    if($_POST['resetbtn']){

        // get the form data
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email  = $_POST['email'];

        // make sure info provided
        if($username){
            if($email){
                if((strlen($email) > 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) && (strstr($email, ".")) ){
                    require("connect.php");
                    $find_email = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
                    if($find_email->num_rows){
                        while($row = $find_email->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                        $email = $row['email'];

                        if($dbemail == $email){
                            $options = [
                                'cost' => 10,
                                'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
                            ];
                            $pass = rand();
                            $pass= password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

                            $query = ("UPDATE `users` SET `password` =? WHERE `username` =?");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$pass,$username);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            if ($stmt->errno) {
                              echo "There was an error updating" . $stmt->error;
                            }
                            else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
                            $stmt->close();

                            // make sure the password was changed

                            $check_update = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password` ='$pass'");
                            if($check_update->num_rows){

                                $webmaster = "fortunefillyvip@homtail.com";
                                $headers = "From: FortuneFilly<$webmaster>";
                                $subject = "Your New Password";
                                $message = "Hello. Your password has been reset. Password: $pass";


                                if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                                    echo"Your password has been reset. An email has been sent with new password.";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo"An error has occured and your email was not sent containing your new password";
                            }
                            else
                                echo"An error has occurred and the password was not reset";
                        }
                        else
                            echo"You entered the wrong email address";

                    }
                    }
                    $result->free();
                    }
                    else
                        echo"The username was not found";

                    mysqli_close();
                }
                else
                    echo "Please enter a valid email";
            }
            else
                echo"Please enter your email";
        }
        else
            echo"Please enter your username";

    }


    echo "<form action='fogotPass.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset password'</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";
}
else
    echo "Please log out to view this page."
?>
```

Comment: You should really avoid coding like this.. those `if` statements could be simply called one after another..

Comment: Maybe problems nearby: "} } $result->free(); }"?

Comment: If there are too any nested blocks, use small functions. They are neat, easy to read and easy to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a good IDE, only in notepad you will make mistakes like that.

Also `if (!$username && !$id){` the variables are not defined.

Your script does too much, query db, validation and print the HTML form.

You have to separate things a little bit.

Take a look:

[image]

- You can see the malformed tags
- You post to the same script yet you have `action='forgotPass.php'`

then in PHP more issues:

[image]

- Again, using IDE you can see the messed up braces other warning

Comment: Also the tablature and the "else" statement without braces are bad.

Comment: What IDE would you recommend?

Comment: Phpstorm is the best out there

Answer (score 1):

- As I can see,you have one extra "}" which is last,above else
  statement .
- Your first if statement ( if (!$username && !$id){ ) is closed just
  before ( echo "form ).
- Also you have not put semicolon (;) at the end of last statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is one extra } bracket at line no. 97

Answer (score 1):

Just remove one of the closing curly braces before "$result->free();".